# Connecting wallet to custom test network

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, testnets

I want to connect my EthereumWallet app up to my private network, I fire up the app but it is trying to connect to the default test network. I get the error

```
Node type: geth
Network: test
Platform: darwin (Architecure x64)

...  config="{ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0 EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10 Engine: ethash}"
INFO [05-18|15:30:40] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/Users/marklar/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [05-18|15:30:40] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/Users/marklar/.ethash                              count=2
INFO [05-18|15:30:40] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=3
INFO [05-18|15:30:40] Loaded most recent local header          number=949371 hash=308cb6…370760 td=670950083564135
INFO [05-18|15:30:40] Loaded most recent local full block      number=949371 hash=308cb6…370760 td=670950083564135
INFO [05-18|15:30:40] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=949371 hash=308cb6…370760 td=670950083564135
WARN [05-18|15:30:40] Blockchain not empty, fast sync disabled 
INFO [05-18|15:30:40] Starting P2P networking 
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: address already in use
```

What am I missing here to get my wallet connecting to my custom test network? Here is my local setup -

CustomGenesis.json

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 15,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },
  "nonce": "0x000000000000002a",
  "difficulty": "0x20000",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "author": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp": "0x00",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "extraData": "0x",
  "gasLimit": "0x2fefd8",
  "alloc": {}
}
```

Then I'm firing this up with

```
geth --rpc --networkid=39318 --maxpeers=0 --datadir=./datatest --ipcpath=./datatest/geth.ipc --mine --minerthreads 1 console CustomGenesis.json
```

This seems to work fine, I get a bunch of mining output

```
INFO [05-18|15:28:50]  mined potential block                  number=540 

hash=3973bc…6e5529
INFO [05-18|15:29:08] Successfully sealed new block            number=541 hash=2a25df…0192a6
INFO [05-18|15:29:08]  block reached canonical chain          number=536 hash=61237c…bf0cb5
INFO [05-18|15:29:08]  mined potential block                  number=541 hash=2a25df…0192a6
INFO [05-18|15:29:08] Commit new mining work                   number=542 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=171.074µs
INFO [05-18|15:29:10] Successfully sealed new block            number=542 hash=2419d9…29a87b
INFO [05-18|15:29:10]  block reached canonical chain          number=537 hash=fd5016…7a94a8
INFO [05-18|15:29:10]  mined potential block                  number=542 hash=2419d9…29a87b
INFO [05-18|15:29:10] Commit new mining work                   number=543 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=277.916µs
INFO [05-18|15:29:15] Successfully sealed new block            number=543 hash=ee3af6…c45936
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. For the time being at least the ipcpath looks to be hard coded in the EthereumWallet. There is a note in the read me about it but you have to set your ipc path to the DEFAULT path for your system.

e.g. on my mac that is - update `--ipcpath=./datatest/geth.ipc` to `--ipcpath=~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc`